# Getting a linting error of no-var-requires

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am getting the error below on running the eslint.

> \helpers\getEnvCredentials.ts
> 4:9  error  Require statement not part of import statement  @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

That error is referring to these lines of code wherein it is saying that using the "require" statement should be use only on imports. Please see (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-var-requires/) for reference

```
const dataCredentials = JSON.parse(
JSON.stringify(
    require("../fixtures/credentials/" + env + "-credentials.json")
    )
);
```

Is there another way to do that line of codes above that will be accepted by eslint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on `eslint` & `node` version, there are three available options.

### Option #1. Disable the rule via inline comment

This one is the easiest:

```js
const dataCredentials = JSON.parse(
JSON.stringify(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    require("../fixtures/credentials/" + env + "-credentials.json")
    )
);
```

### Option #2. Use FileSystem module to read JSON files

```js
import fs from "node:fs";

// I don't know whether `fs` will resolve the relative path correctly,
// so better use absolute path.
const dataCredentialsLocation = new URL(
  `../fixtures/credentials/${env}-credentials.json`, import.meta.url,
);

// readFileSync returns a buffer that has to be converted into a string.
const dataCredentialsString = fs.readFileSync(dataCredentialsLocation).toString();

// The string can be parsed into an object.
const dataCredentials = JSON.parse(dataCredentialsString);
```

### Option #3. Split ESLint config

If you're using ["flat" ESLint config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide#eslintrc-examples), you can specify what rules should be disabled for NodeJS modules.